# Structure pointer dereference

Tags: pointers, data-structures, dereference

I am trying to pass a structure of point array as shown, how can I correctly dereference the address to change the value the address points to.

```
// header file "header.h"
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} Pointbase;
typedef Pointbase *XYpt;

typedef struct {
    XYpt xy[1];
} ChartPointsbase;
typedef ChartPointsbase **PointArray;

#include "header.h"
...

void npCluster(double drop, XYpt *newpt, PointArray outpts)
{
    double xx[2]={-15, 100};
    int i;
    outpts = (PointArray)malloc(sizeof(PointArray) * 2);
    for (i=0;i<2; i++) 
    {
        (*(*outpts)->xy[i])->x=xx[i];
        (*(*outpts)->xy[i])->y=drop;
    }
}
```

The complier likes the following line but does not compute

```
        (*outpts)->xy[i]->y=drop;
```

Any suggestions will be most appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to add that I want to use this function to manipulate various point arrays to plot charts. Typical size of the point array is 3000 double points.

Comment: You have an array containing one pointer: `XYpt xy[1];` Indexing from 0 upto 2 will not be valid : `->xy[i]` [and: *please* remove the silly typedefs. They are only confusing]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for "c" compiler as follows:
Define struct with two 1D arrays each of size dimsize, allocate memory to handles, set the size =k, and dereference as follows:

```
for (i=0; i<k; i=i++)
        {
            (*(outpts->xx))->dat[i]=135*i+j;
            (*(outpts->yy))->dat[i]=drop;
        }
```

For further nesting, say struct array of the above with two unequal point arrays, where cht is an array of PointArray

```
typedef struct {
    int32 dimSize;
    C1Hdl cht[1];
} XYchartCluster;

// initialize 1st array
for (i=0; i<k; i=i++)
        {
            (*(*(xycht)->cht[0])->xx)->dat[i]=135*i+j;
            (*(*(xycht)->cht[0])->yy)->dat[i]=drop;
        }
// initialize 2nd array with values from point npt
for (i=0; i<sz; i=i++)
        {
            (*(*(xycht)->cht[1])->xx)->dat[i]=npt->x;
            (*(*(xycht)->cht[1])->yy)->dat[i]=npt->y;
        }


/*
Note: size of each array in chart should be initialized and 
memory assigned (dynamically changing size)
*/
```